# Relationship in parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I've created this relationship from the documentation, but whatever i do i seem to keep getting an error:

```
Error: invalid type for key storeId, expected relation<stores>, but got *stores (Code: 111, Version: 1.2.19)
```

parse code:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"stores"];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:storeID block:^(PFObject *objects, NSError *error) {

    PFObject *myNumber = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"users"];
    myNumber[@"user"] = @1;
    myNumber[@"udid"] = [UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor.UUIDString;
    // Add a relation
    myNumber[@"storeId"] = objects;
    [myNumber saveInBackground];
}];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this will help?

```
[[myNumber relationForKey:@"storeId"] addObject:objects];
```

It may help the legibility of your code if you made `objects` singular, since it only represents one object. It could also help if you named it something more descriptive than objects.